# cuda __launch_bounds__() intellisense error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda, intellisense

I'm using VS2012, CUDA 5.5 SDK

once I add `__launch_bounds__()` to a kernel, VS intellisense go mad with lots of errors `incomplete type is not allowed`

I searched for the definition in the headers, found in `"host_defines.h"`,

```
#define __launch_bounds__(...) \
        __annotate__(launch_bounds(__VA_ARGS__))
```

the compile for the project is working fine, just intellisense is wrong

edit:
example of cuda kernel

```
__global__ void kernel(int* result, int* input){} //fine
__global__ void __launch_bounds__(256, 8) kernel(int* result, int* input){} //intellisense error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
    #define L(x,y) __launch_bounds__(x,y)
#else
    #define L(x,y)
#endif

__global__ void L(256, 8) kernel(int* result, int* input){}
```

this compiles fine without intellisense problems